# Toggle event hides my div for no reason

Tags: jquery, setinterval

Hi I have a checkbox that I want to toggle. When I click/check the first time, it starts the setinterval (starts my slideshow) and when I click a second time, it stops the slideshow (clearinterval). But for no reason, it hides/display:none my checkbox when the page loads...

```
$("#start").toggle(function ()
            {
                var interval = setInterval(function() 
                {
                    alert("hey")
                    Img++
                    if (Img == 27)
                        {
                            Img = 0;
                        }
                    $("[src='images/slideshow2/carre/slideImg" + Img + ".jpg']").fadeIn()
                    $("#imgRonde").attr("src", "images/slideshow2/carre/slideImg" + Img + ".jpg");
                    $(".grandeurori").attr("href", "images/slideshow2/slideImg" + Img + ".jpg");
                }, 3000);


            }, function ()
            {
                clearInterval(interval)
            })
```

Hopefuly, you can help me.

Comment: The `.toggle()` event was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9  (http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). The `.toggle()` effect still exists and its purpose is to hide/display elements.

Answer (score 1):

`.toggle()` is not a way to trigger an event on your checkbox. It is a function to hide/show. You want to use `.change()`

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: This is true as of 1.9.  Previously there was an event called toggle which took 2 functions which were called alternating on each click.

Comment: Huh... well at least what I said was true when I said it. But thanks, good to know.

Comment: But .change() only works if the checkbox value changes, not if it's checked or not...

Comment: @Maxwell Not exactly sure what you mean... how else are you using a checkbox? When you click it the first time, do a check if it's checked. If so, start your slide show. If it's not checked, stop your slide show.

Answer (score 0):

The toggle you are trying to use was removed in jquery 1.9:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

it is instead calling this toggle:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/